# E2e testcase in angular not running due to version mismatch of chromedriver with chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, angular-e2e

My angular version is 7, the protractor version is 5.4.4 and Os is ubuntu. When I am trying to run the e2e test case from the command `ng e2e` following errors are coming.

> [11:19:32] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88
> Current browser version is 87.0.4280.141 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
> (Driver info: chromedriver=88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}),platform=Linux 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64)
> [11:19:32] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88
> Current browser version is 87.0.4280.141 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
> (Driver info: chromedriver=88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}),platform=Linux 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64)

After getting this error I tried to change the downgrade version of chrome driver also in the angular project from this command `sudo webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 87.0.4280.88`  But the same error occurs again.

Comment: there are different installations of webdriver. `sudo webdriver-manager` refers to global, try to install chromedriver in local webdriver

Comment: Thanks, Sergey Pleshakov for your answer yeah I did the same. Previously I was changing the version for global not for local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue and steps are as follows :

- ADD chrome driver version 87.0.4280.88 with this command   `node node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=87.0.4280.88`
- Add  `chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_87.0.4280.88', in protractor.conf.js`